# Redis Exporter : what is Encrypted port for Prometheus at Redis?

Tags: redis, prometheus

https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter#basic-prometheus-configuration says 9121. it is unencrypted port. is there any encrypted mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no support for https in prometheus to exporters But it's in development phase to add native ssl support between the two component